# SQL SELECT Date as different FORMAT when using MAX(date)

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

In my Table, the date is stored as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Currently I convert this to `dd-mm-yyyy` via a loop in php. This seems incredibly ineficient. Is there a way of converting it within the SQL.

My current `sql` is:

```
SELECT gameName , Max(modified) as modified
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY gameName 
ORDER BY modified ASC;
```

I tired adding `DATE_FORMAT(Max(modified),'%m-%d-%Y')` but this did not work. I am using `PDO`

Comment: What datatype are you using to store the date?

Comment: Why did your code "not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way, why are you saying it does not work:

```
SELECT gameName , date_format(Max(modified), '%d-%m-%Y') as modified
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY gameName 
ORDER BY modified ASC
```

Obviously, you need to use a timestamp format for the *modified* column, not varchar.

Comment: You could also just use DATE(MAX(MODIFIED))